# PHP OOP Multicall

Tags: php, oop

i have seen in some libraries something like this :

```
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
```

How is this 'multicall' done, or, how should the class be build to do something like this?

I think :

```
class greeting
{
    public function hi()
    {
        public function howAreYou()
        {
            echo 'How are you?';
        }
    }
}
$greet = new greeting;
$greet->hi()->howAreYou();
```

But i think it's not so good, i would better use something like extends, but i don't know. Thx for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a class instance calling itself, it is called "method chaining".

In PHP, can be done by using `return $this`; note that this is a very different mechanism than class inheritance - it doesn't really make sense to treat them as interchangeable.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=method+chaining+php

Answer (score 3):

`getResponse()` is returning a class instance which has a `setRedirect()` method.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function getResponse()
    {
        $redirect = new Bar();
        return $redirect;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public function setRedirect($returnUrl)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

$foo->getResponse()->setRedirect("returnUrl");
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

All you have to do is return self at very end of each function.

So Your example would be like>

```
class greeting
{
    public function hi()
    {
        echo "Hi";

        return $this;
    }

    public function howAreYou()
    {
        echo 'How are you?';

        return $this;
    }
}

$greet = new greeting;
$greet->hi()->howAreYou();
```

Or even:

```
$greet->hi()->howAreYou()->hi()->howAreYou();
```

Comment: The keyword you have been looking for is **method chaining**. :-)

Comment: I think you mean `$this`, not `self` (your code sample is correct).

Comment: @YMMD yep, I read it after I submitted my answer within another answer I cannot find now anymore (somebody deleted it?).

Anyway I was always low with theory, I'm rather practical being... :-)

Comment: @Piskvor No, I ment `self` as if You return `$this` within a method of a class You return the instance of `itself`.

Comment: @shadyyx: Ah, okay, now I understand. I was confused by `self` as a PHP language construct versus `self` as a natural language construct :)

Answer (score 1):

Chaining methods is not the same as declaring functions within a method... in fact the latter will spit an error (not the function declaration, but the way you're calling it). In order to chain a method, just have it return the object itself:

```
Class chainableObject
{
    public $name=null;
    public function __construct($name='')
    {
        $this->name=$name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;//makes chainable
    }

    public function greet()
    {
        echo 'Hello, '.$this->name;
        return $this;
    }
}

$chain = new chainableObject('Frank')->greet();//outputs: Hello, frank
```

The explanation: All methods return the instance itself, so basically, read the last line of the snippet like this [create object with name:Frank]=>call method greet on the return value of this action. Since the return value is `$this`, the object that has a greet method, that's what will happen... easy, for more info: just google *php method chaining*

Answer (score 1):

```
    class stutter{
      public function a(){
      echo 'h';
      return $this;
     }
      public function b(){
       echo 'hello world!';
     }
    }
```

$var=new stutter();
var->a()->b();

Output is:

> h hello world